# Cannot use IOS distribution certificate

Tags: xcode

I need to upload an app on the account of a client. I logged in with xcode but I can't select the IOS distribution code signing profile, I tried to download the IOS distribution certificate from their member center 
[image]

But even if I download it and double click in order to install it on the keychain I cannot use it.. Should I create a new IOS distribution certificate or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure. I think you need to have their developer profile installed on your computer. It will want you to export the profile from the keychain on their Mac and you would install on yours. If they only have an account but do not use it for anything other than to sell their app you might be in a better position to just set it up on yours. If they do have it installed then it can be a bit tricky. I don't expect this to be an answer but I hope it helps you find the solution.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use it, because private key should exist at your machine for this certificate, you cannot download it from anywhere except the export process from machine for which it was generated. In your case request new certificate for your machine.